# How can I drill into a table by filtering SQL for final result?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following data:

Base Table
    LineNumber  Hcpcs   DateOfService   Mod1    Mod2    Mod3    Mod4    Mod5    RenderingNpi

```
1          A1111    1/5/2016    RT                                   1234567890
2          B2222    1/6/2016    76                                   1234567890
3          C3333    1/5/2016    77                                   1234567890
4          A1111    1/5/2016    LT                                   1234567890
5          B2222    1/6/2016    77                                   1234567890
6          B2222    1/6/2016    --                                   1234567890
7          E5555    1/5/2016                                         1234567890
```

Here's a graphic showing the above data:

[image]

Now, I need to find all the records with the same procedure, which I've done, here:

```
BEGIN

    set nocount on

        SELECT hcpcs, COUNT(*)
        FROM base_table
        GROUP BY hcpcs
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    set nocount off

END

-- The result:
-------------------------
-- A1111    2016-01-05  2
-- B2222    2016-01-06  3
```

Now, with those, I need to locate the following:  A111 and B2222 have the same Dates of service.

The result will be the same, of course, so, will my query just be the same but adding the DateOfService to it like so:

```
BEGIN

    set nocount on

        SELECT hcpcs, date_of_service, COUNT(*)
        FROM base_table
        GROUP BY hcpcs, date_of_service
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    set nocount off

END
```

Then, I have to find if the LineFromDate has a modifier = "RT" and if any of the others have "LT".

I've found a function that helps me...

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_FindStringInTable]    Script Date: 12/4/2017 8:46:55 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FindStringInTable] @stringToFind VARCHAR(100), @schema sysname, @table sysname 
AS

BEGIN TRY
   DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WHERE ' 

   SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @stringToFind + ''' OR '
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
   AND TABLE_NAME = @table 
   AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')

   SET @sqlCommand = left(@sqlCommand,len(@sqlCommand)-3)
   EXEC (@sqlCommand)
   PRINT @sqlCommand
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
   PRINT 'There was an error. Check to make sure object exists.'
   PRINT error_message()
END CATCH
```

And call it like so:

```
BEGIN

    EXEC dbo.sp_FindStringInTable '%T%', 'dbo', 'base_table'

END
```

and I have other filtering SSRS features I need to complete but if I can get over this roadblock, I can solve the rest.

Yes, this is a test, but I'm simply trying to understand how to DRILL down into data...

Essentially, I simply want to do this:

if I find each procedure in the claim appears on other lines then if that result contains the same LineFromData, then I keep going...

and so on... just want to make sure I'm on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: That function is way too verbose for what you are doing. Surely you don't need to search every column in every table in the database for a value. You know which columns the data resides in. Using `WHERE` and `HAVING` seem to be all you need.